# Is there a way to fill an image with its background color to square size?

Tags: command-line, bash, gimp, image-processing, imagemagick

Let me describe my problem:

I have a site where I post sponsors company logos. Once I'm sent the logo (or I've googled) they are usually in rectangle size - width and height are not equal.
On my site, once you upload the logo image, you then crop it to a square.

For logos that are rectangular, I usually open them up in GIMP, increase the canvas size to a square, create a new layer of the background color and finally export it as jpg or png for the site. Quite time consuming.

I'm looking for a way to do that hopefully with just a terminal command.

#### EXAMPLE:

Consider this Safaricom (Kenyan Telecommunication company) logo below. It's of 650px by 380px - how can I make it 650px by 650px and then center it horizontally from the command line?

[image: safaricom logo]

Comment: The question could be more appropriate at [graphicdesign.se](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), although it is not off topic here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following command which requires `imagemagick` (`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`):

```
pic="ty338.png"; convert $pic -trim $pic ; width=$(identify -format "%w" $pic); height=$(identify -format "%h" $pic); new_dim=$((width > height ? width+10 : height+10)); convert $pic -gravity center -extent "${new_dim}x${new_dim}" $pic
```

- The first `convert` command trims your picture to remove borders
- Then I use `identify` to find the max dimension (width or height)
- I add a 10px border (feel free to change or remove it)
- Finally the last `convert` command use `-gravity` to center the logo in a square canvas.

You can even paste this command into a bash function in your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
squarize()
{
    pic=$1
    convert $pic -trim $pic
    width=$(identify -format "%w" $pic)
    height=$(identify -format "%h" $pic)
    new_dim=$((width > height ? width+10 : height+10))
    convert $pic -gravity center -extent "${new_dim}x${new_dim}" $pic
}
```

Comment: Nice. Is there any way I can make this into a function? something like squarize(pic.png)

Comment: @Parto Good idea, I've updated my answer. Add the above lines in your `~/.bashrc`, reload your shell and just type `squarize mypic`